# Caret will not work in Bash regular expression?

Tags: regex, bash, caret

I'm trying to match lines corresponding to image placements in Markdown files, so I can replace the address of each image, where appropriate, with a value from an array. The lines look like this:

```
![Alt text.](/!/image.jpg)
```

Note, the image address itself, within the parentheses, contains an exclamation mark as this indicates it needs to be replaced with a real address. So `image.jpg` acts as the key for an array I have created.

Say the value for the key `image.jpg` is `http://images.com/an-example-image.jpg`. The desired result for my Bash script would be:

```
![Alt text.](http://images.com/an-example-image.jpg)
```

I've been using a conditional operator in Bash to do this...

```
testfile=$(<test-md.md)
re='(.*)\!(.*\()\/\!\/([0-9a-z\.\-]+)(\).*)'
while [[ $testfile =~ $re ]]; do
    testfile=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"!"${BASH_REMATCH[2]}${imagemap[${BASH_REMATCH[3]}]}${BASH_REMATCH[4]}
done
```

So far so good.

But I don't want to capture these lines like this if they're part of a blockquote or code, only those that would be parsed by Markdown as an actual image.

I thought I could avoid this by insisting that the exclamation mark that begins the image placement be at the very start of the line. Here's the regular expression I've tried:

```
re='(.*)^\!(.*\()\/\!\/([0-9a-z\.\-]+)(\).*)'
```

Unfortunately, Bash doesn't seem to want to recognise the caret when I do this. The replacement still works but even if the line is in code, it gets replaced. For example, this Markdown file:

```
![Alt text.](/!/image.jpg)

This image was placed with the following code:

    ![Alt text.](/!/image.jpg)
```

Unfortunately becomes this:

```
![Alt text.](http://images.com/an-example-image.jpg)

This image was placed with the following code:

    ![Alt text.](http://images.com/an-example-image.jpg)
```

It *should* be this:

```
![Alt text.](http://images.com/an-example-image.jpg)

This image was originally placed with the following code:

    ![Alt text.](/!/image.jpg)
```

I've also tried using line break character class instead of the caret:

```
re='(.*)[\n\r]+\!(.*\()\/\!\/([0-9a-z\.\-]+)(\).*)'
```

That doesn't work either, so I could be I've missed something important about Bash regular expressions in general.

Am I using the caret incorrectly in this case? How can I capture just those instances where the image placement starts at the beginning of a line?

Comment: note that `.*` is greedy which matches upto the last character greedily.

Comment: Why would this have an effect on the match in these particular cases?

Comment: Why you included two `!` symbols in your regex where the input contains only one?

Comment: Thanks for picking up on this. I've edited my question to include a note: I'm actually looking for addresses which contain an additional exclamation mark as these are the ones I want to replace.

Comment: could you provide the expected output for the above input? And also provide some more examples.

Comment: @guypursey: what do you want to do with the links? list all urls?

Comment: I have added a bit more detail with examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Avinsah Raj in the comments for giving me the clue to this one. I couldn't see it at first but there seems to be no way to make the Kleene star in Bash regex non-greedy. (Happy to be corrected if this is wrong.)

I found that if I altered the regex so that we look for printable characters only after the first exclamation mark and prior to the opening parenthesis, then the capture works. It must have been too wide before and capturing line breaks to find an earlier exclamation mark on a previous unrelated line.

So the correct regex is:

```
re='(.*^\!\[[[:print:]]+\]\()\/\!\/([0-9a-z\.\-]+)(\).*)'
```

With this in place, the caret works and only image placements at the start of a line are found and replaced accordingly.

This has been driving me mad all afternoon, so many thanks Avinsah!

Comment: i think this `^(\!.*\()\/\!\/([0-9a-z\.\-]+)(\).*)` will also work. You need to put `^` symbol at the start which represents that we are at the start of a line.

Comment: Thanks! I'm not sure this one meets my needs quite as well (I need all the stuff that precedes the exclamation mark) but I appreciate the effort. I have given you a nod in [my blog post on this](http://scriptogr.am/guypursey/post/201501181933-image-handling).

Comment: wow, you could ask me any help regarding regex at any time :-).

Answer (score 0):

On the risk of downvoting, I would advice you **not** to use regular expressions, since markdown is quite complicated. Chances are pretty large you will always miss some aspects like for instance backquotes, code environments, code inside custom html code,...

You can however use `pandoc` to convert the markdown in a more generic format like `html` and then use for instance `xmllint` to capture the image url's:

```
pandoc -f markdown -t html | xmllint --html --xpath '//img/@src' -
```

If you perform this on your given example, one gets:

```
$ echo '![Alt text.](/!/image.jpg)' | pandoc -f markdown -t html | xmllint --html --xpath '//img/@src' -
 src="/!/image.jpg"
```

`pandoc` is a program that is designed to convert all types of document formats into each other. By calling `pandoc -f markdown -t html` you convert given *markdown* into html. A more easy to parse format.

`xmllint` is a program to query xml documents. In this case we provided the query `//img/@src` wich means:

> Return all `src` attributes of all `<img>` tags in the input.

Comment: Thanks. Not going to downvote, but I am trying to this with just Bash, partly to reduce dependencies and partly to learn more about pure Bash scripting. That's why I've avoided `sed` and `awk`.

Comment: @guypursey: I think you can't even do this by a *one-per-line* regex since you can open and close a code block using three backquotes as you can see [here](https://github.com/rstudio/rmarkdown/issues/323#issuecomment-65948269). So you will need at least some kind of "*state*"...